# Get user name from a document in Firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to display the user name on the profile page. I have tried multiple things but every time it shows an error.

This is what I have done so far:

```
  Widget userProfile(BuildContext context) {
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> provideDocumentUserName() {
  return Firestore.instance.collection('user').document('name').snapshots();
}

return Container(
    child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: provideDocumentUserName(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            Map<String, dynamic> documentFields = snapshot.data.data;
            return Text(documentFields["name"]);
          }
        }));
```

The error I'm getting is:

> The getter 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> data

Also:

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

I have been working on this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like snapshot.data is null and that's why you might be seeing this error. you might want to check the connection state. one way to tackle is as follows:

```
  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.done:
      if (snapshot.hasError)
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      Map<String, dynamic> documentFields = snapshot.data;
      return Text(documentFields["name"]);
  }
  return CircularProgressIndicator(); // unreachable
```

Courtesy to @cipli-onat post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321523/fluter-futurebuilder-not-getting-asyncsnapshot-data)

Answer (score 0):

You should get *documentFields* as follow:

```
Map<String, dynamic> documentFields = snapshot.data.data();
```

Comment: it says "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked."